# Ionic 3 (ion-datetime) Possible to show both preassigned value AND placeholder?

Tags: ionic3

I'm building an Ionic 3 app which contains an **ion-datetime** picker to select a date. I was requested to start the selection from a specific date (to prevent older users from having to scroll too much), but still allowing the user to choose newer or older dates compared to that preassigned value.

So my ion-datetime looks like this:

```
<ion-datetime type="date" displayFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY" pickerFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY" placeholder="Select Date" [max]="today" [(ngModel)]="startingDate" // more parameters after that>
```

In this case, '`today`' is the current date, set  with the usual `const date = new Date();` , whereas '`startingDate`' is set programatically on component initialization, taking the current `date` and substracting 18 years from there. It works well and if today is the 19th of March 2019, startingDate is set to be the 19th of March, 2001.

So good, so far. With one problem: with a predetermined starting value assigned with ngModel, the 'placeholder' attribute gets overriden. This could lead to my users believing that the date was preselected for them, or accidentally skimming over the date input and sending the wrong value.

My point: can I make the `placeholder` attribute with a text indicator like the one in the code, and the default value set by `[(ngModel)]="startingDate"` coexist in the view? The point would not be to show both values in the input box, but to have the preassigned value ready to pre-fill the date selector when the user clicks the field. I have tried changing the use of an [(ngModel)] to a [value] assignation (both with and without the []), but in that scenario the value does not set inside my datetime picker.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can use is string interpolation for your placeholder and use the same variable for your pre-selected Date.

```
<ion-datetime type="date" displayFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY" pickerFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY" placeholder={{startingDate}} [max]="today" ngModel // more parameters after that>
```

In some cases if you haven't manipulated your date string you will get the full Date value because the *pickerFormat* and *displayFormat* don't recognize the placeholder value.

You can change the look to however you want.

```
public Date: any = new Date();

public startingDate: any = this.Date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + this.Date.getDate()+  '/' + (this.Date.getFullYear() - 18);
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, not exactly what I was looking for (although you did make me see that part of the premise of the question wasn't clear enough and I've edited it, so thanks for that!). What I'm looking for is a textual placeholder like the one in my original post, so that the user will see the text 'Select date' before he/she opens the datetime picker to make a choice.

Comment: @JurgenBlitz I'm a bit confused. So you want the placeholder, but you also want the startingDate to show? or just show once the form field is selected?

Comment: the idea is for the placeholder to show before the user clicks on the input. Currently, if I include no placeholder, when I click on the actual datetime selector the 'wheel' for the date is already set to my startingDate. I want to keep that behaviour, but to enable the placeholder so it can be present until the user clicks.